# Bitbucket to GitHub migration: tree contains duplicate file entries

Tags: git, github, migration

I want to transfer a Bitbucket repository to GitHub.

199 out of 200 repositories are successful, and only one repository fails.

I ran the command below and try to transfer to GitHub:

```bash
git clone --mirror bitbucket-repo
git remote set-url --push origin github-repo
git push --mirror
```

The following error occurs.

```
Total 160096 (delta 113339), reused 160096 (delta 113339), pack-reused 0
remote: error: object 2ae1195cbbfa963a8ac2d0947a17facc1f78a73b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
remote: fatal: fsck error in packed object
```

The result of the query in that tree.

```bash
git ls-tree 2ae1195cbbfa963a8ac2d0947a17facc1f78a73b
```

```
    040000 tree 04871142b0800418f012f8ef943a37ea20d015d8    Test
    100644 blob 3a0096dd091fa4974857cf4dbe00609f557565d8    number.swift
    100644 blob 3a0096dd091fa4974857cf4dbe00609f557565d8    number.swift
    100644 blob aeb3c43345266b9de0900fdb7967dc8e1e91ec04    number.xib
    100644 blob aeb3c43345266b9de0900fdb7967dc8e1e91ec04    number.xib
```

We have a history of changing the first letter of the `number.swift` and `number.xib` file names to `n` -> `N` as shown in the picture below.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you per chance using an OS with a case-insensitive filesystem? macOS filesystems do (or did) that, I believe.